# Imagemagick -adjoin results in multiple files

Tags: pdf, imagemagick, png

I'm using ImageMagick on Windows to convert a PDF into a PNG.
The PDF have three pages and I use this command to convert it :

```
convert -density 900x900 -resize 1920x1080 -quality 50 -adjoin EULA.pdf pdfpng.pdf.png
```

The result is three png which are the three pages.

[The PDF I use](http://www.mediafire.com/view/?gqte1iia0g3o2bi)

Any idea on how to convert it into one single file ?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works in Linux. Sorry, but I can't access to a Windows machine (besides of no idea of shell programming in that system). I hope it can be useful for you in any way:

```
for page in {0..2}; do 
    convert -density 900x900 -resize 1920x1080 -quality 50 "EULA.pdf[$page]" +adjoin miff:-
done | convert - -append eula.png
```

It loops for every page in the `pdf` file and with all pages generates a temporal (only in memory) file which format is specific to `ImageMagick`. This data is piped to a process that only concatenates all them in vertical (the minus sign of `append`) to output file `eula.png`.